# Rename multiple files with timestamp - windows

Tags: windows, cmd, file-rename

i have multiple files a in directory (Windows 7 OS). I want to rename all of them with `same name + timestamp`

What is its CMD Syntax.

Comment: what programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Considering you want to get the current system timestamp, below command would work

```
REN "*.txt" "*_%Date:/= %_%Time::=.%.txt"
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work on MS-DOS. Please don't use the ms-dos tag for questions about the Windows command prompt. They're are two different things.

Comment: @RossRidge Ouch, sorry